# An induction proof of $(a+1)^n (a^n+1) \leq 2^n (a^{2n}+1)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, polynomials, induction, factoring

Prove by induction that for every $n \in \mathbb{N} $
$$
(a+b)^n (a^n+b^n) \leq 2^n (a^{2n} +b^{2n}) \qquad a, b>0.
$$
We can remark this equality is equivalent to
$$
(a+1)^n (a^n+1) \leq 2^n (a^{2n}+1) \qquad a>0.
$$

Comment: I think, without induction it's shorter.

Comment: Yes, but the question is to prouvr it by induction and this is why i can't get quickly the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n=1$ we have
$$2(a^2+1)\geq(a+1)^2$$ or $$(a-1)^2\geq0.$$
Let $$2^n\left(a^{2n}+1\right)\geq(a+1)^n\left(a^n+1\right).$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$2^{n+1}\left(a^{2n+2}+1\right)\geq(a+1)^{n+1}\left(a^{n+1}+1\right)$$ and since
$$(a+1)^n\leq\frac{2^n\left(a^{2n}+1\right)}{a^n+1},$$ it's enough to prove that
$$2^{n+1}\left(a^{2n+2}+1\right)\geq\frac{2^n\left(a^{2n}+1\right)(a+1)\left(a^{n+1}+1\right)}{a^n+1}.$$
But $$a^{2n+2}+1\geq\frac{\left(a^{2n+1}+1\right)\left(a^{n+1}+1\right)}{a^n+1}$$ it's
$$\left(a^{n+1}-1\right)(a-1)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$2\left(a^{2n+1}+1\right)\geq\left(a^{2n}+1\right)(a+1)$$ or
$$\left(a^{2n}-1\right)(a-1)\geq0.$$
Done!

Comment: Yes it's not too obvious. But thanks you.

Comment: You are welcome!